# How to write a boolean constructor in javascript?

Tags: constructor, boolean

I am making constructor in js.
I dont know how to write boolean type in a constructor
I want variable order as a boolean type .
Is it right way to type like this?

```
function Hamburger(menu,price,order){
    this.menu = menu;
    this.price = price;
    this.order = false; 
    
}
```

Please let me know !
THank uou

I tried to search on google cant find it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript function definitions do not specify data types for parameters (as illustrated in "[JavaScript Function Parameters](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-function-parameters/)").

> - There is no need to specify the data type for parameters in JavaScript function definitions.
> - It does not perform type-checking based on the passed-in JavaScript functions.
> - It does not check the number of received arguments.

So using a [constructor](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp) is enough, and in your case, instead of `this.order = false;` (which always affect false to `order`), you can use `this.order = order;` (which uses the `order` parameter)